# Solving for a Rotation Matrix Equation $R_1 R_\mathrm{x} R_2 = R_\mathrm{x}$

Tags: matrices, rotations, matrix-equations, quaternions

I would like to solve for an equation $R_1 R_\mathrm{x} R_2 = R_\mathrm{x}$ where $R_1$, $R_2$, and $R_\mathrm{x}$ are $ 3 \times 3 $ rotation matrices, $R_1$ and $R_2$ are known, and $R_\mathrm{x}$ is unknown.  How do I get the solution $R_\mathrm{x}$?

An idea is to represent each rotation matrix as a quaternion, and then compute the elements; how ever it seems to be complicated to me.

If you know a better way, please tell me.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note in the below that the inverse of any rotation matrix is its transpose.
We can proceed as follows:
$$
R_1 R_x R_2 = R_x \iff\\
R_1 R_x R_2 R_x^T = I \iff\\
R_x R_2 R_x^T = R_1^T
$$
That is, there will only be a solution matrix $R_x$ if $R_2$ is unitarily similar to $R_1^T$.  This is only the case if $R_1$ and $R_2$ are rotations by the same angle about possibly different axes.  Assuming this is the case, we can solve this as follows:

First, find an orthogonal $U_1$ so that
$$
U_1 R_1 U_1^T = R_\theta := 
\pmatrix{\cos \theta & -\sin \theta &0\\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1}
$$
(This is a well known problem with known solution algorithms).  We can then find an orthogonal $U_2$ so that
$$
U_2 R_2 U_2^T = R_\theta := 
\pmatrix{\cos \theta & -\sin \theta &0\\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1}
$$
It follows that
$$
R_1^T = U_1^T R_\theta^T U_1 = U_1^T U_2 R_2 (U_1^T U_2)^T
$$
That is, we have the solution $R_x = U_1^T U_2$.  So long as we ensure that $\det(U_1)$ and $\det(U_2)$ are positive (which is necessarily possible), we guarantee that $R_x = U_1^T U_2$ is a rotation, as desired.

If you prefer, you may take
$$
R_\theta = \pmatrix{e^{i\theta} & 0&0\\0&e^{-i\theta}&0\\0&0&1}
$$

---

For a construction of such a matrix $R_x$, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4233151/81360) (but replace $R_2$ with $R_2^T$).

Comment: Thank you!  The solution is "only the case if R1 and R2 are rotations by the same angle about possibly different axes", which is a reasonable solution in my case (actually that is a calibration problem in computer vision; what you pointed out is physically correct).  Let me ask one more question; **how do I compute the orthogonal matrices U1 and U2?**  Can I use a standard way like using QR decomposition, etc.?

Comment: @Akihiko you're looking for a *spectral decomposition*, which can be done using the standard eigendecomposition algorithm with a normalization or using any [Schur decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition) algorithms such as the [QR algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm).

Comment: @Akihiko the catch is that, as I said, you need to make sure that $\det(U_1)$ and $\det(U_2)$ have the same sign, so that $R_x$ ends up being a rotation.  In order to flip the sign without affecting the validity of the solution, you can simply multiply the third column of either $U_1$ or $U_2$ by $-1$.  Or, just multiply the whole matrix by $-1$ if you prefer.

Comment: Now the things are more clear. I will try to implement above. Thanks so much, @Omnomnomnom.

Answer (score 0):

Let $R_1=Rot(\Delta_1,\theta_1),R_2=Rot(\Delta_2,\theta_2)$. Note that $R_1=R_x{R_2}^{-1}{R_x}^{-1}$ and $R_1$ is similar to ${R_2}^{-1}$, that is equivalent to $\theta_1=\pm \theta_2\; mod \;2\pi$. Conversely, if $\theta_1=\pm\theta_2\;mod\;2\pi$, then the main condition is that the rotation $R_x$ sends the oriented line $\Delta_2$ to the oriented line $\pm \Delta_1$.

Answer (score 0):

I have almost the same problem that solving the matrix equation:
$$R_1R_x=R_xR_2$$
where $R_1$, $R_2$ and $R_x$ are all rotation matrixes.

I have studied @Akihiko's answer but due to my poor mathematical foundation, I still don't know the exact solution.

Could you tell me a more specific way to use spectral decomposition or QR decomposition?

By the way, have you published any papers about your solution to the calibration problem?

I'd appreciate any help.