# Solve rotation matrix equation with orthonormality constraint by Lagrange multipliers

Tags: matrix-equations, lagrange-multiplier, orthogonal-matrices

I want to find the $R_x \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$, that minimizes
$$
||(R_1R_x-R_xR_2)||_F^2
$$
subject to the orthonormality constraint
$$
R_x^T R_x=I
$$
where $R_1$, $R_2$ and $R_x$ are all rotation matrixes (orthogonal and $det(\cdot)=1$), $R_1$ and $R_2$ are both known.

**I tried:**

I apply the Lagrange multiplier method to the problem:
$$
min \quad J(R_x) = {\rm tr}((R_1R_x-R_xR_2)^T(R_1R_x-R_xR_2)+(R_x^TR_x-I)Y)
$$
where $Y$ is a symmetric matrix.
I take the derivative of the equation above and set it equal to zero:
$$
\frac{\partial(J(R_x))}{\partial(R_x)} = R_x(4I+2Y)-2R_1^TR_xR_2-2R_1R_xR_2^T=0 \\
R_1^TR_xR_2+R_1R_xR_2^T =R_x(2I+Y)
$$
so I'm stuck here. I don't know how to solve a matrix equation like this, involving an unknown symmetric matrix $Y$.

Can anyone help me or give me some suggestions?

Thanks very much in advance.

---

**New:**

I found a Question that is almost the same as mine [solving-for-a-rotation-matrix-equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882978/solving-for-a-rotation-matrix-equation-r-1-r-mathrmx-r-2-r-mathrmx/).

According to that answer, maybe I was wrong to use Lagrange multiplier method.

And solving the matrix equation:
$$R_1R_x=R_xR_2$$
where $R_1$, $R_2$ and $R_x$ are all rotation matrixes.
@Ben Grossmann's solution is using *spectral decomposition* or *Schur decomposition* such as QR.

I'm sorry for my poor knowledge of matrix theory. I still don't know the exact solution.

Can anyone tell me the more clear solution?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi York, I got your email. I'll try to put together an answer when I find the time

Comment: Why is $Y$ a symmetric matrix? I'm not familiar with this version of the Lagrange multiplier method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on my earlier answer, here is a solution that works in the case that an exact solution is possible (i.e. the minimum is zero). Unlike the solution that I had in mind at the time, this does not involve the use of complex numbers.

As I state in my post, a rotation $R_x$ such that $R_1R_x = R_xR_2$ exists if and only if $R_1,R_2$ are rotations by the same angle, possibly about different axes. Let $u_1$ denote an axis of rotation of $R_1$ (one of the two unit vectors from the null space of $R_1 - I$). Extend this vector to a right-handed orthonormal basis $(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ of $\Bbb R^3$. Let $U$ denote the matrix whose columns are $u_1,u_2,u_3$. We must have
$$
U^TR_1U = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0\\0 & \cos \theta & -\sin \theta\\ 0 & \sin \theta & \cos \theta}
$$
for some angle $\theta \in [0,2 \pi)$ (incidentally, we must have $\operatorname{tr}(R_1) = 1 + 2 \cos \theta$).

Let $v_1$ denote an axis of rotation of $R_2$. Extend this vector to a right-handed orthonormal basis $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ of $\Bbb R^3$. Let $V$ denote the matrix whose columns are $v_1,v_2,v_3$. One of two equations must hold:
$$
V^TR_2V = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0\\0 & \cos \theta & \sin \theta\\0 & - \sin \theta & \cos \theta} 
\quad \text{or} \quad 
V^TR_2V = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0\\0 & \cos \theta & -\sin \theta\\0 & \sin \theta & \cos \theta}.
$$
If the first equation holds, replace $v_1$ with $-v_1$ and $v_2$ with $-v_2$. With the new matrix $V$, the second equation now holds.

With that, we have found rotation matrices $U$ and $V$ such that
$$
U^TR_1U = V^TR_2V \implies R_1 UV^T = UV^T R_2.
$$
Thus, we can take $R_x = UV^T$.

---

A bit of detail about $U$ and $V$:

One approach is as follows. Write $u_1 = (u_{11},u_{21},u_{31})$. We want *any* vector $u_2$ that is perpendicular to $u_1$; if $u_1$ is not $\pm (0,0,1)$, then one such option is to take $v = (u_{21},-u_{11},0)$ and let $u_2$ be the normalized vector in this direction, $u_2 = v/\|v\|$. To get the $u_3$ that makes for a right-handed orthonormal basis, we can compute the cross-product
$$
u_3 = u_1 \times u_2.
$$

Comment: Thank you sooo much for your reply. My understanding is that the key to this solution is the rotations by the same angle, thus constructing the equations for R1 and R2. I extracted the rotation axis and angle from $R_1$ and $R_2$, and then tried to solve for $U$ and $V$ but failed. I'm sorry, can you tell me how to compute $U$ and $V$?

Comment: Furthermore, I don't really understand the construction of $U^TR_1U=R_\theta$. "Extend the rotation axis to a right-handed orthonormal basis", maybe it's related to the YZ plane? Is there any relevant knowledge or paper that I need to understand? And, I really appreciate your time and patience!

Comment: @York See my latest edit. If you're doing this as part of a script, then you might prefer to build $U$ using a built in "null space" method.

Comment: @York See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4160055/81360). A bit of a catch there: if you use either of the algorithms I recommend in the link, then you'll need an additional step to make sure that the columns of $U$ are a right-handed basis. To that end, it suffices to flip the sign of one of the columns if $\det(U) = -1$.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I have understood the implementation steps, and the test is complete. Actually, $U$ and $V$ are randomly generated, as long as a 3D orthogonal basis is satisfied and the first column is the rotation axis. And all the equations work. However, how careless I am... The $R_x$ is not unique! ... ... Let me ask one more question if I have $n$ of these equations, $\{R^A_iR^x = R^xR^B_i, i=1,2,...,n\}$, is it possible to get a unique $R^x$?

Comment: I suspect that it is possible. That said, I'm not sure what would be required to ensure that a solution exists in the case of $n$ equations.

Comment: I understand. I need to reanalyze my original problem and think about solutions. Your advice also helped me understand the roration matrix equation better. Thank you very much for your help, sincerely.